# Taking numbers from a loop and applying them to a np.zeros array?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code for plotting a `one-dimensional walk`. In this instance, I'm trying to graph how the distance travelled changes with the number of steps taken per walk, which increases by an increment of `10` each time, from `10` steps to `1000`. Because I wasn't able to make the dimensions work normally, I tried making a `np.zeros` array for each value of the distance. At the moment I have this:

```
minstep = 10
step_max = 1000
increment = 10

nsteps = np.arange(minstep,step_max+increment, increment)

for nsteps in range(step_max):
    nwalks = 10
    distance = np.zeros(nwalks) 
    for j in range(nwalks):
        startpos = 0.0
        pos=startpos
        for i in range(nstep):
            x = 0.5-random.random() 
            step = math.copysign(1.0, x) 
            stepsize = -1 * math.log(1 - random.random())         
            pos=pos+ (step * stepsize)
        distance[j] = (math.fabs(pos-startpos))
    nsteps = nsteps + increment
    distance_total = np.zeros(99)
    nsteps_total = np.arange(minstep, step_max, increment)
    distance_total[nwalks]=distance
```

So, I'm trying to take each value of distance, and apply it to a corresponding spot in the `distance_total` array, but I'm not sure, how would I get each value of distance to be assigned to a zero in the `distance_total` array.

Comment: I can't understand what your actual *question* is. What happened when you tried running the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: It's an error for the "distance_total[nwalks]=distance with the error being 'setting an array element with a sequence'

Comment: You set `distance = np.zeros(nwalks)` and then you assign `distance` to `distance_total[nwalks]` - that's assigning a sequence to an array element, so that seems like the correct error message. What did you expect to be the result of `distance_total[nwalks]=distance`?

Comment: you're problem definition is very unclear and difficult to understand what you are actually trying to achieve. It will be better if you explain a bit more